# Background image in Chrome table cell?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Trying to get a background image to display in a single table cell  element in Chrome...and it will, but only when I hover over that cell. If I remove the :hover, it just doesn't display no matter what I do.

I'm asking this question now in the hope that Google has fixed this issue and I haven't seen the answer after searching, or someone has figured it out. The other reason is that there are search results from 2010 and they mostly talk about table row elements instead of single cells.

This fails to give me my image in a table cell:

```
#matrix td.level {
position: relative;
vertical-align: top;
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
background: transparent url("/images/th-bg-level.png") no-repeat 0px bottom;
}
```

But I can hover just fine:

```
#matrix td.level:hover {
background: transparent url(/images/th-bg-level.png) no-repeat -157px bottom;
border: none;
}
```

It also will show the image if I change to a `<th>` element, but I don't really want to do that...bad coding practice and all...

Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: Your url reference to the image is in a different location compared to the `:hover`. The same is true for your `background-position` value. I'm not sure if that's just a typo though.

Comment: Typo - bad editing on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Using backgrounds on `<td>` elements works fine, the issue must be somewhere else.

```css
td {
  padding: 30px;
}
td.target {
  background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/cAN2O2J.jpg") no-repeat 0px bottom;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td class="target">Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The hover state and the non-hover state in your code address completely different folders (`/images/` vs `../images/`), isn't the problem there?

Comment: the directory references I just typed wrong. Mistake on my part. I'll have to look at the other things that might be causing an issue. It's possible I'm having inheritance issues...